# A counter-example to differential function but not twice differential

Tags: calculus, derivatives, examples-counterexamples

Find a function $f$ that is differentiable, but not twice differentiable and which does not belong to the following type: $$f(x) = \begin{cases} x^\alpha \sin(x^{\beta}) & x \neq 0 \\ 0 & x=0.\end{cases}$$
Please give me a hint.

Comment: Add a constant.

Comment: Actually that class of functions is often used for examples of differentiable functions that are not $C^{1}$: do you mean that?

Comment: A [similar](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/653829) question.

Answer (score 4):

$x\mapsto x|x|$ should be a good candidate.

Answer (score 1):

Consider $F$ an antiderivative of $x\to |x|$

Is $F$ twice differentiable?

Answer (score 0):

Take the anti-derivative of the [Weierstrass function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_function) which is continuous everywhere and differentiable nowhere.